# Accessing environment variable within config file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, environment-variables

I'm using Vuejs to develop an app, I want to know that how can I access environment variables within config file.

For example I have `.env.development` file which contains `VUE_APP_BASE_URL = "http://some.ip/contex"` variable, is there a way to use this variable like this:

```
VUE_APP_BASE_URL = "http://some.ip/contex"
VUE_APP_API_ADDRESS = $VUE_APP_BASE_URL + "/some/api"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this, but  you would  need to install `dotenv`:

```
const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', ../.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}) });


Vue_API: process.env['VUE_APP_BASE_URL'],
```

Comment: You don't really need third-party library for accessing the `.env.*` variables as they are readily accessible across your application via the `process.env.[your_variable]`.

Answer (score 0):

You want [computed `env` vars](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#using-env-variables-in-client-side-code).

#### .env.development

```
VUE_APP_BASE_URL = "http://some.ip/contex"
```

#### vue.config.js

```js
process.env.VUE_APP_API_ADDRESS = process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL + "/some/api";
```